# SCSS kebab-case does not work with scss modules in React (typescript template)

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I have created a new React project using `create-react-app` with Typescript template. I use SCSS and try to use CSS modules approach. But I see that my SCSS classes are applied when I specify them in `camelCase` notation only. This is not good for me. I would like to use classical `kebab-case` CSS notation.

This works for me, but I dislike it:

```css
.authContainer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

this does not work, but I like it

```
.auth-container {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the example of the component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Kek.module.scss';

const Kek = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.authContainer}>
            !!!!!!!!!!! HELLO WORLD !!!!!!!!!!!
        </div>
    );
};

export default Kek;
```

Here is an illustration what is going on
[image]

How to fix that? Am I supposed to create a `webpack.config.js` to override something? I made some research, and I think, yes, I'm. But, I'm not sure about how this overriding might look like. Too little information about this case.

#### UPDATE

As I was advised in comments, I tried to override `exportLocalsConvention` of `css-loader`. [Documentation link](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)

But it's not so easy to override something from `webpack.config.js`. To do that I installed the `react-app-rewired` npm package. I added the following config to my project:

```js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.module.rules.push({
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
            modules: {
                exportLocalsConvention : 'dashes'
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(config)

    return config;
}
```

`console.log(config)` shows me that I really have objects from the `webpack.config.js`. But then there is a problem. When I open my application, I see this:
[image]

I have installed `css-lodaer`. What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work"?

Comment: @Arkellys if I have styles in kebab-case, I get nothing instead of classes, just empty strings. If I have them in camelCase, then I get them.

Comment: I can't really test this but take a look at the options `exportLocalsConvention` or `localsConvention` of `css-loader`

Comment: @Arkellys I thought about them. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're overriding CRA's webpack config, you probably want to keep the original config as much as possible to avoid unwanted errors. You can see the original config of CRA [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js).

Writing something like this should allow you to change `exportLocalsConvention` without changing anything else:

```
const cssLoader = require.resolve("css-loader");
const isTestingSassModuleRegex = (test) => test.toString() === "/\.module\.(scss|sass)$/";

module.exports = {
    webpack: function (config) {
        config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
            if (!rule.hasOwnProperty("oneOf")) return;

            rule.oneOf.forEach(loader => {
                if (!loader.test || !isTestingSassModuleRegex(loader.test)) return;

                loader.use.forEach(styleLoader => {
                    if (styleLoader.loader !== cssLoader) return;
                    styleLoader.options.modules.exportLocalsConvention = "asIs";
                });
            });
        });

        return config;
    }
};
```

This should be compatible with CRA `v5.0.0`.

This config will only override the loader for SASS module files (it targets [this part](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/c20ccecfa1cf130a47d37908dc54959c618ce8ea/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L572) of the original config), since it seems to be what you use. If you need to change the options for CSS or regular SASS files as well, you need to remove or change the condition `!isTestingSassModuleRegex(loader.test)`.

Comment: Please note that I didn't test this config so it may not work the first time. I will fix the mistakes if there are any.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried it, it does not work, unfortunately. Are you sure I have to touch exactly sass loader? Does it have the option like `exportLocalsConvention `. I know that `css-loader` has. I tried to change `css-loader` using your approach. There was also no effect.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak with the code I provided we are changing the options of `css-loader`. It's the condition in the last `forEach`, we return if we are on a different loader.

Comment: In the original config, we can see four loaders for the styles, each one targeting different files (`.css`, `.module.css`, `.scss/sass` and `.module.sass/scss`). All of them then call `getStyleLoaders()` which will set up `css-loader`, `postcss-loader`, etc. Since you use SASS module, we first target the loader for `.module.scss` files and then edit the options of `css-loader`.

Comment: If you can confirm that the config override set the option correctly, but that it still doesn't work then maybe we didn't set up `exportLocalsConvention` correctly. Could you try with `"asIs"` instead of `"dashes"`?

Comment: (I mixed up the semantic a bit in my previous comment, "we can see four loaders for the styles" -> I meant that there are four tests for style files. Each of them set multiple loaders for these files.)